# PHP preg_match User Number List Input

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, preg-match

I am working on a small modification to a WordPress plugin. The user enters in the page/post numbers into a textbox that they want to exclude from a list.

I need to filter the input and then check it to see if it should be included in the mySQL SELECT. Can someone please help with this snippet? I can't seem to get it to work. I am not very familiar with preg_match expressions. I would like to make sure that there are only numbers and commas in the input. Testing different preg_match is always returning 0 on me.

Answer Bonus: If possible make sure it is then output so it will not break the SQL. This code just accepts or denies entry without "fixing" it.

Good Numbers = "213" or "213, 252"
Bad Numbers = Blank, "two seventy three", "Red is a color."

PHP

```
if ((!empty($excludedPagesPosts)) && (preg_match('/^[0-9\,]$/', $excludedPagesPosts))){
    $exclude = 'ID Not In ($excludedPagesPosts) And';
} else {
    $exclude = '';
}
```

mySQL

```
$sql = "    SELECT 
                ID, 
                post_title, 
                post_modified 
            FROM
                {$wpdb->posts} 
            WHERE
                $exclude
                post_status = 'publish' AND
                {$postTypeWhere} 
            ORDER BY post_modified DESC";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression only match one character. To match one or more characters add `+`. Also there no need to escape `,`. So correct expression:

```
/^[0-9,]+$/
```

Bonus (with check to no break SQL):

```
/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/
```

The same but allow spaces:

```
/^ *[0-9]+ *(, *[0-9]+ *)*$/
```

You can experiment with various expressions here: http://regex101.com/r/rD9oC7/1

Comment: Thanks for this it works! It's nice to know that it can do both things. Also thanks for the link. I will use that in the future for sure.

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice:

```
if (preg_match('/\A[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*\z/', $excludedPagesPosts))
```

No need to test if `$excludedPagesPosts` is empty, since the pattern will fail in this case.

**pattern details:**

```
\A           # anchor for the start of the string
[0-9]+       # one or more digits
(?:          # open a non-capturing group
    ,        # literal comma (no need to escape it)
    [0-9]+   # one or more digits
)*           # repeat the group zero or more times
\z           # anchor for the end of the string
```

Note: you can add an optional space after the comma: `/\A[0-9]+(?:, ?[0-9]+)*\z/`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on not checking if empty. It makes sense it will fail on an empty preg_match.